Error: Expected '(' but got identifier. ```function getUsdValue(address token, uint256 amount) public view returns (uint256) {```

// This is considered an Exogenous, Decentralized, Anchored (pegged), Crypto Collateralized low volitility coin

// Layout of Contract:
// version
// imports
// interfaces, libraries, contracts
// errors
// Type declarations
// State variables
// Events
// Modifiers
// Functions

// Layout of Functions:
// constructor
// receive function (if exists)
// fallback function (if exists)
// external
// public
// internal
// private
// view & pure functions

pragma solidity 0.8.20;

import { DecentralizedStableCoin } from "./DecentralizedStableCoin.sol";
import { ReentrancyGuard } from "@openzeppelin/contracts/security/ReentrancyGuard.sol";
import { IERC20 } from "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import { AggregatorV3Interface } from "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/shared/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";

/*
 * @title DecentralizedStableCoin
 * @author EddiePumpin
 *
 * * The system is designed to be as minimal as possible, and have the tokens maintain a 1 token == $1 peg at all times.
 * This is a stablecoin with the properties:
 * - Exogenously Collateralized
 * - Dollar Pegged
 * - Algorithmically Stable
 *
 * It is similar to DAI if DAI had no governance, no fees, and was backed by only WETH and WBTC.
 *
 * Our DSC system should always be "overcollateralized". At no point, should the value of
 * all collateral < the $ backed value of all the DSC.
 *
 * @notice This contract is the core of the Decentralized Stablecoin system. It handles all the logic
 * for minting and redeeming DSC, as well as depositing and withdrawing collateral.
 * @notice This contract is based on the MakerDAO DSS system
 */

contract DSCEngine is ReentrancyGuard {
    ///////////////////
    // Errors
    ///////////////////
    error DSCEngine__NeedsMoreThanZero();
    error DSCEngine__TokenAddressesAndPriceFeedAddressesMustBeSameLength();
    error DSCEngine__NotAllowedToken();
    error DSCEngine__TransferFailed();
    error DSCEngine__BreaksHealthFactor(uint256 healthFactor);
    error DSCEngine__MintFailed();
    error DSCEngine__HealthFactorOk();
    error DSCEngine__HealthFactorNotImproved();

    ///////////////////
    // State Variables
    ///////////////////
    uint256 private constant ADDITIONAL_FEED_PRECISION = 1e10;
    uint256 private constant PRECISION = 1e18;
    uint256 private constant LIQUIDATION_THRESHOLD = 50; // If your collateral's value drops below 50% of the amount you've borrowed, your position could be liquidated.
    uint256 private constant LIQUIDATION_PRECISION = 100;
    uint256 private constant MIN_HEALTH_FACTOR = 1e18;
    uint256 private constant LIQUIDATION_BONUS = 10;

    mapping(address token => address priceFeed) private s_priceFeeds;
    mapping(address user => mapping(address token => uint256 amount)) private s_collateralDeposited;
    mapping(address user => uint256 amountDscMinted) private s_DSCMinted;
    address[] private s_collateralTokens;

    DecentralizedStableCoin private immutable i_dsc;

    ///////////////////
    // Events
    ///////////////////
    event CollateralDeposited(address indexed user, address indexed token, uint256 amount);
    event CollateralRedeemed(address indexed redeemedFrom, address indexed redeemedTo, uimt256 indexed token, uint256 amount);

    ///////////////////
    // Modifiers
    ///////////////////
    modifier moreThanzero(uint256 amount) {
        if (amount == 0) {
            revert DSCEngine__NeedsMoreThanZero();
        }
        _;
    }

    modifier isAllowedToken(address token) {
        if (s_priceFeeds[token] == address(0)) {
            revert DSCEngine__NotAllowedToken();
        }
        _;
    }

    ///////////////////
    // Functions
    ///////////////////
    constructor(address[] memory tokenAddresses, address[] memory priceFeedAddresses, address dscAddress) {
        if (tokenAddresses.length != priceFeedAddresses.length) {
            revert DSCEngine__TokenAddressesAndPriceFeedAddressesMustBeSameLength();
        }

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < tokenAddresses.length; i++) {
            s_priceFeeds[tokenAddresses[i]] = priceFeedAddresses[i];
            s_collateralTokens.push(tokenAddresses[i]);
        }

        i_dsc = DecentralizedStableCoin(dscAddress);
    }

    ///////////////////
    // External Functions
    ///////////////////

    /*
    * @param tokenCollateralAddress: the address of the token to deposit as collateral
    * @param amountCollateral: The amount of collateral to deposit
    * @param amountDscToMint: The amount of DecentralizedStableCoin to mint
    * @notice: This function will deposit your collateral and mint DSC in one transaction
    */
    function depositCollateralAndMintDsc(address tokenCollateralAddress, uint256 amountCollateral, uint256 amountDscToMint) external { 
        depositCollateral(tokenCollateralAddress, amountCollateral);
        mintDsc(amountDscToMint);
    }

    /**
     * @notice follows CEI(Checks Effects Interaction)
     * @param tokenCollateralAddress The address of the token/Coin to deposit as collect
     * @param amountCollateral The amount of collatral to deposit
     */
    function depositCollateral(
        address tokenCollateralAddress,
        uint256 amountCollateral
    )
        public
        moreThanzero(amountCollateral)
        isAllowedToken(tokenCollateralAddress)
        nonReentrant
    {
        s_collateralDeposited[msg.sender][tokenCollateralAddress] += amountCollateral;
        emit CollateralDeposited(msg.sender, tokenCollateralAddress, amountCollateral);
        bool success = IERC20(tokenCollateralAddress).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amountCollateral);
        if (!success) {
            revert DSCEngine__TransferFailed();
        }
    }

    /*
    * @param tokenCollateralAddress: the collateral address to redeem
    * @param amountCollateral: amount of collateral to redeem
    * @param amountDscToBurn: amount of DSC to burn
    * This function burns DSC and redeems underlying collateral in one transaction
    */
    function redeemCollateralForDsc(address tokenCollateralAddress, uint256 amountCollateral, uint256 amountDscToBurn) external {
        burnDsc(amountDscToBurn);
        redeemCollateral(tokenCollateralAddress, amountCollateral);
    }

    // In order to redeem collateral:
    // The health factor must be over 1 AFTER collateral pulled.
    function redeemCollateral(address tokenCollateralAddress, uint256 amountCollateral) external moreThanzero() nonReentrant{
        // s_collateralDeposited[msg.sender][tokenCollateralAddress] -= amountCollateral; // Since we are updating the state, we need to emit an event
        // emit CollateralRedeemed(msg.sender, tokenCollateralAddress, amountCollateral);
        // bool success = IERC20(tokenCollateralAddress).transfer(msg.sender, amountCollateral);
        // if(!success){
        //     revert DSCEngine__TransferFailed();
        // }
        _redeemCollateral(msg.sender, msg.sender, tokenCollateralAddress, amountCollateral);
        _revertIfHealthFactorIsBroken(msg.sender);
    }

    /**
     * @notice follows CEI(Checks Effects Interaction)
     * @param amountDscToMint amount of decentralized stable coin to mint
     * @notice they must have more collateral value than the minimum threshold
     */
    function mintDsc(uint256 amountDscToMint) public moreThanzero(amountDscToMint) nonReentrant {
        s_DSCMinted[msg.sender] += amountDscMinted;
        _revertIfHealthFactorIsBroken(msg.sender);
        bool minted = i_dsc.mint(msg.sender, amountDscToMint);
        if(!minted) {
            revert DSCEngine__MintFailed();
        }
    }

    function burnDSC(uint256 amount) public moreThanzero(amount) {
        _burnDsc(amount, msg.sender, msg.sender);
        revertIfHealthFactorIsBroken(msg.sender);
    }

    /*
    * @param collateral: The ERC20 token address of the collateral you're using to make the protocol solvent again.
    * This is collateral that you're going to take from the user who is insolvent.
    * In return, you have to burn your DSC to pay off their debt, but you don't pay off your own.
    * @param user: The user who is insolvent. They have to have a _healthFactor below MIN_HEALTH_FACTOR
    * @param debtToCover: The amount of DSC you want to burn to cover the user's debt.
    *
    * @notice: You can partially liquidate a user.
    * @notice: You will get a 10% LIQUIDATION_BONUS for taking the users funds.
    * @notice: This function working assumes that the protocol will be roughly 150% overcollateralized in order for this to work.
    * @notice: A known bug would be if the protocol was only 100% collateralized, we wouldn't be able to liquidate anyone.
    * For example, if the price of the collateral plummeted before anyone could be liquidated.
    */
    function liquidate(address collateral, address user, uint256 debtToCover) moreThanzero(debtToCover) nonReentrant external {
        // Check the health factor of user
        uint256 startingUserHealthFactor = _healthFactor(user);
        if (userHealthFactor >= MIN_HEALTH_FACTOR){
            revert DSCEngine__HealthFactorOk();
        }
        // We want to burn their DSC "debt" and take their collateral
        uint256 tokenAmountFromDebtCovered = getTokenAmountFromUsd(collateral, debtToCover); // When we pay the debt, How much of this token are we going to get?
        // We give liquidator 10% bonus
        uint256 bonusCollateral = (tokenAmountFromDebtCovered * LIQUIDATION_BONUS) / LIQUIDATION_PRECISION; // uint256 private constant LIQUIDATION_BONUS = 10;
        uint256 totalCollateralRedeemed = tokenAmountFromDebtCovered + bonusCollateral;
        _redeemCollateral(msg.sender, msg.sender, tokenCollateralAddress, amountCollateral);
        _burnDsc(debtToCover, user, msg.sender);

        // Check the health factor if it has improved before this function call finishes
        uint256 endingUserHealthFactor = _healthFactor(user);
        if(endingUserHealthFactor <= startingUserHealthFactor){
            revert DSCEngine__HealthFactorNotImproved();
        }
        _revertIfHealthFactorIsBroken(msg.sender); // It should revert if liquidator's health factor has been broken

    }

    function getHealthFactor() external view { }

    ///////////////////
    // Private & Internal View Functions
    ///////////////////

    /**
     * @dev Low-level internal function, do not call unless the function calling it is checking for the health factors being broken
     */
    function _burnDsc(uint256 amountDscToBurn, address onBehalfOf, address dscFrom) private moreThanZero(amount){
        s_DSCMinted[onBehalfOf] -= amount; // onBehalfOf was msg.sender
        bool success = i_dsc.transferFrom(dscFrom, address(this), amount); // dscFrom is the liquidator
        if(!success){
            revert DSCEngine__TransferFailed();
        }
        i_dsc.burn(amount);
    }

    // From is the debtor while to is the liquidator
    function _redeemCollateral(address tokenCollateralAddress, uint256 amountCollateral, address from, address to) private {
        s_collateralDeposited[from][tokenCollateralAddress] -= amountCollateral;
        emit CollateralRedeemed(from, to, tokenCollateralAddress, amountCollateral);

        bool success = IERC20(tokenCollateralAddress).transfer(to, amountCollateral);
        if(!success){
            revert DSCEngine__TransferFailed();
        }
    }

    function _getAccountInformation(address user)
        private
        view
        returns (uint256 totalDSCMinted, uint256 collateralValueInUsd)
    {
        totalDSCMinted = s_DSCMinted[user];
        collateralValueInUsd = getAccountCollateralValue(user);
    }

    /**
     * Returns how close to liquidationa user is
     * If a user goes below 1, then they can get liquidated
     * @param user
     */
    function _healthFactor(address user) private view {
        // We need DSC minted and total collateral VALUE
        (uint256 totalDSCMinted, uint256 collateralValueInUsd) = _getAccountInformation(user);
        //return (collateralValueInUsd/totalDSCMinted);
        uint256 collateralAdjustedForThreshold = (collateralValueInUsd * LIQUIDATION_THRESHOLD) / LIQUIDATION_PRECISION;
        return (collateralAdjustedForThreshold * PRECISION) / totalDscMinted;
    }

    function _revertIfHealthFactorIsBroken(address user) internal view {
        uint256 userHealthFactor = _healthFactor(user);
        if(userHealthFactor < MIN_HEALTH_FACTOR){
            revert DSCEngine__BreaksHealthFactor(userHealthFactor);
        }
    }

    ///////////////////
    // Public & External View Functions
    ///////////////////
    function getTokenAmountFromUsd(address token, uint256 usdAmountInWei) public view returns(uint256) {
        AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(s_priceFeeds[token]);
        (, int256 price,,,) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
        return (usdAmountInWei * PRECISION) / (uint256(price) * ADDITIONAL_FEED_PRECISION);
    }

    function getAccountCollateralValue(address user) public view returns (uint256 totalCollateralValueInUsd) {
        // Loop through each collateral token, get the amount they have deposited and map it to the price to get the USD
        // value.
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < s_collateralTokens.length; i++) {
            address token = s_collateralTokens[i];
            uint256 amount = s_collateralDeposited[user][token];
            totalCollateralValueInUsd += getUsdValue(token, amount);
        }
        return totalCollateralValueInUsd;

        function getUsdValue(address token, uint256 amount) public view returns (uint256) {
            AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(s_priceFeeds[token]); // Retrieves the Chainlink price feed contract for the given token.
            (, int256 price,,,) = priceFeed.latestRoundData(); // The price is the 1 of the token in USD 
            return ((uint256(price) * ADDITIONAL_FEED_PRECISION) * amount)/PRECISION; // Price is multiplied with 10e8 because the decimal of ETH/USD is 8
        }
    }
}


You’ve defined the getUsdValue function inside the scope of the getAccountCollateralValue function.
Just move the getUsdValue function outside that scope, like:
function getAccountCollateralValue(address user) public view returns (uint256 totalCollateralValueInUsd) {
    // Loop through each collateral token, get the amount they have deposited and map it to the price to get the USD
    // value.
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < s_collateralTokens.length; i++) {
            address token = s_collateralTokens[i];
            uint256 amount = s_collateralDeposited[user][token];
            totalCollateralValueInUsd += getUsdValue(token, amount);
    }
    return totalCollateralValueInUsd;
}

function getUsdValue(address token, uint256 amount) public view returns (uint256) {
    AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(s_priceFeeds[token]); // Retrieves the Chainlink price feed contract for the given token.
    (, int256 price,,,) = priceFeed.latestRoundData(); // The price is the 1 of the token in USD 
    return ((uint256(price) * ADDITIONAL_FEED_PRECISION) * amount)/PRECISION; // Price is multiplied with 10e8 because the decimal of ETH/USD is 8
}


Oh! I didn't see that. Thanks ASAD
